# Twitter API, "Unable to verify your credentials."

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

Exactly what it says on the tin.

By all means, this code should be working. It's following exactly what the https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only page says. Yet, it keeps returning `{{"errors":[{"code":99,"message":"Unable to verify your credentials","label":"authenticity_token_error"}]}
[Finished in 0.551s]`, and I have no idea why.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer("[key]:[secretkey]").toString('base64'),
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: "grant_type=client_credentials"
};

request.post(options, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

As a quick note, the key and secretkey were omitted from this code here due to the inherent sensitivity of it being present. You can place your own key/secretkey in there to try it, but I am unwilling to provide my own.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The issue originally was that contentType should've been Content-Type, and that technically fixed it, but in reality it only changed the error that I was getting.

UPDATE:

Transcoding the buffer key to base64 and back shows that the integrity of the authorization key remains intact throughout the encoding process, and that Basic [base64keyhash] is valid according to the documentation provided by Twitter.

Comment: The docs list

"If attempted too frequently, requests will be rejected with a HTTP 403 with code 99."

Maybe try with a fresh client until you get it working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already specifying method: "POST" in the options, try to use request() instead of request.post():

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer("[key]:[secretkey]").toString('base64'),
    "contentType":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: "grant_type=client_credentials"
};

request(options, function(error, response, body){
  if(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response.statusCode, body);
  }
});
```